# Proving the growth theorem for functions of $S$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am having some trouble understanding a proof that uses arc length integration and I think I could use some help. 
Suppose we have a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ that is 1-1 and $f(0)=0$. Suppose also that we have an inequality $|f'(z)|\geq\frac{1-|z|}{(1+|z|)^3}$ for all $z$ in the unit disk. 
My goal is to prove that if the segment $[0,f(z_0)]$ lies inside $f(\mathbb{D})$, then $|f(z_0)|\geq\frac{|z_0|}{(1+|z_0|)^2}$. This is part of the growth theorem from Duren's book.

Now let's suppose that we have the segment $[0, f(z_0)]$ and let $C$ be its preimage through $f$. Then obviously $f(z_0)=\displaystyle{\int_C f'(\zeta)d\zeta}$.
Now it is $f(z_0)=\displaystyle{\int_C f'(\zeta)d\zeta=\int_a^b (f\circ C)'(t)dt}$. But as $t$ traverses $[a,b]$, $f\circ C$ traverses the segment that joins the origin with a point, hence the argument stays constant. Consequently,

$|f(z_0)|=\displaystyle{|\int_C f'(\zeta)d\zeta|=\int_C|f'(z)||dz|\geq\int_0^{|z_0|}\frac{1-s}{(1+s)^3}ds=\frac{|z_0|}{(1+|z_0|)^2}}$

My question concerns the inequality above. It is obvious in an intuitional way, but I can't get a rigorous proof. In my knowledge the arc length integral $\int_\gamma h(z)|dz|$ is defined as $\int_a^bh(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt$. But if I use this definition in the inequality I get the following: 
$\displaystyle{\int_a^b |f'(C(t))||C'(t)|dt\geq\int_a^b\frac{1-|C(t)|}{(1+|C(t)|)^3}|C'(t)|dt}$.

But now I don't know how to handle this. Setting $u=|C(t)|$ is tempting but I believe this is not a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of the obvious intervals. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on your parametrisation of $C$ of course. But $C$ is a smooth curve, so you can parametrise it smoothly (including $C'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I believe you re refering to the last thing I said. $C$ is indeed a Jordan curve but what worries me in setting $u=|C'(t)|$ is the modulus. Wont it mess up the differentiability?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the last sentence of your question. Taking the modulus will not mess up differentiability. $z \mapsto \lvert z\rvert$ is (arbitrarily often) real-differentiable on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, so the only possible problem with differentiability is at $t = 0$ where $C(t) = 0$ (I'm assuming $a = 0$ for simplicity of notation). But $C(t) = b\cdot t + O(t^2)$ near $0$, which yields $\lvert C(t)\rvert = \lvert b\rvert\cdot t + O(t^2)$ near $0$. But if you set $u = \lvert C(t)\rvert$, note that $\frac{du}{dt} \neq \lvert C'(t)\rvert$ in general.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see; so this change of variables doesn't really help. Thanks dor the clarification though!

Answer (score 1):

The following lemma should help:

Lemma: If $\gamma :[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is differentiable, and $\gamma (t) \ne 0$ for $t\in (a,b],$ then

$$|\gamma |'(t) \le |\gamma'(t)|\,\,\, \text {for } t\in (a,b].$$

Proof: Let $\gamma (t) = x(t) + iy(t).$ Then $|\gamma (t)| = (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$ For $t\in (a,b],$ we have

$$|\gamma|' = \frac{xx' +yy'}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} \le \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}((x')^2+(y')^2)^{1/2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} = ((x')^2+(y')^2)^{1/2} =|\gamma '|.$$

Note that we've used Cauchy-Schwartz on the numerator.

Comment: I see. I guess this will help a lot, but note that the theorem states also that equality holds only for rotations of the Koebe function. So it should also be shown that the preimage of the segment through a rotation of the Koebe function satisfies the equality in the used CS inequality. I believe I can do that on my own, but do you think that my reasoning is correct?